# Android - too many open files error: possible to view all open files and threads?

Tags: android

I have been getting an intermittent "too many open files" error on an Android device I'm developing for. It only seems to manifest if the code is left running for several days (its a piece of data gathering software running on a standalone smart-watch, so this is normal behavior).

Having done some research it looks like this is (probably) being caused by opening files and not closing them, either through poor coding practice (I have just fixed as much of this as I can find and have moved file operations into try-catch-finally blocks); or possibly through something going wrong with the multi-threading. I run two background processes using IntentServices which open and write to files and which should close them as part of normal operation, unless something is going wrong.

This brings me to the questions:

1 - is it possible (through logcat or adb, or otherwise) to examine all the open files a particular app has at any given point in time?
2 - is it possible to see what  threads an app has and what is running in them at an arbitrary point in time? I know I can set a break-point and debug the code but would like to leave it running for a few hours before I look at the threads.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same.